# When click on li add hidden class to all li but not to the clicked li and remove class if already available to that li using jquery

Tags: jquery

In list of three list items when i click on Item1 hidden class should be apply to Item2 and Item3 and when second time click on Item2 it should check and remove previously added hidden class and now apply  hidden class to Item 1,Item 2 using jquery i have written script for that but not getting as expected?

```
<ul class="main-menu">
  <li class="">list 1</li>
  <li class="">list 2</li>
  <li class="">list 3</li>

</ul>



 <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
    var link = $('.main-menu li');

     $(this).on('click', function () {
     link.not($(this)).parent().addClass('hide-class');

     if($(this).hasClass('hide-class')){
     $(this).removeClass('hide-class');
   }
});

});

    </script>
```

Comment: `link.not($(this)).parent().addClass('hide-class');` Read it out loud: So get the lis, not the current li that was clicked, get the parent (ul), and add a class to the ul.

Comment: @epascarello can you please write working script ,actually i don't have that much idea about jquery

Comment: There is NO reason to select the parent.... So remove that part of the code. And I am not sure how you would click on an li that is hidden.

Comment: @epascarello just consider hidden-class not hidden property

Comment: So you need to select the lis of the parent.... or just use siblings....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So select the siblings, not the parent element

```
$('.main-menu').on('click', 'li', function () {  // listen to clicks on the li
    $(this)  // li that was clicked
     .removeClass('hide-class')  // remove the class
     .siblings()  // get the li's siblings
       .addClass('hide-class')  // add the class
});
```